Why my Image API is not returning image data in React Native
When I fetched my API service then it gave me JSON Parsing issue at first but I changed the data type to URL from JSON and I can't get the Image API data properly
I was expecting to Render the data to the <Image/> tag properly from the API
This is My API Service:
const APIService = async (category: any) => {
  const URL = `https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/randomimage?category=${category}`;
  const APIKEY = 'SECRET';
  try {
    const response = await fetch(URL, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'X-Api-Key': APIKEY,
        Accept: 'image/jpg',
      },
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch image');
    }
    return response.url;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};

export default APIService;

HomeScreen.tsx:
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Button, Image, View} from 'react-native';
import APIService from '../../service/api_service/api_service';

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState(undefined);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await APIService('abstract');
      setImageUrl(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Generate Image" onPress={fetchData} />
      {imageUrl && (
        <Image source={{uri: imageUrl}} style={{width: 200, height: 200}} />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;



Shouldn't post your API Key . Need to get into the practice of making that an env variable: Setting environment variable in react-native?

APIService is returning url (response.url) not an actual image.

can you tell me how can i fix that this is the documentary of the API I'm using: https://api-ninjas.com/api/randomimage
